# Django: redirect user to provide more information and on success redirect to previous URL

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-views

I know that I can use decorators such as `@login_required` and `@permission_required()` or enclose a view in a function like `login_required()` to redirect a user to sort of provide more information (log in in that case). On success the user is redirected to the URL he was trying to access in the first place (automatically using the logic `?next=/` in the URL).

Now I would like to apply the `?next=/` logic to another case. My user is logged in and wants to claim a piece on the website. To successfully do this he must have provided his address. In the view I check if all the address fields are not empty. If one of the fields is empty I redirect the user to a default `UpdateView` (form). If the user filled in the fields (clicks the submit button) I would like to redirect him to the URL he came from (trying to claim the piece). Due to this redirect the process of checking if all address fields are not empty would start over and if it succeeds this time the piece is claimed.

How does the `?next=/` logic apply in such a case?

**views.py**

```
from django.views.generic import RedirectView
from django.http import QueryDict
class ClaimRedirectView(RedirectView):
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'street', 'street_number', 'zip_code', 'state_province', 'location', 'country']

    permanent = False

    def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
        claimant = get_object_or_404(Creator, user=self.request.user)
        missing_fields = [fields.name for fields in claimant._meta.get_fields(include_hidden=False) if fields.name in self.REQUIRED_FIELDS and not getattr(claimant, fields.attname, None)]

        if not missing_fields:
            return reverse('my-claimed')

        messages.info(self.request, 'Please fill in your complete address to proceed')
        next = self.request.get_full_path()

        path = reverse('creator-update', kwargs={'slug': claimant.slug})
        #q = QueryDict('next=%s' % next)
        q = 'next=' + next

        return '%s?%s' % (path, q)

class CreatorUpdate(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Creator
    slug_field = 'slug'
    fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'street', 'street_number', 'zip_code', 'location', 'state_province', 'country']

    # these two methods only give access to the users own profile but not the others
    def user_passes_test(self, request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            self.object = self.get_object()
            return self.object.user == request.user
        return False

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.user_passes_test(request):
            return redirect_to_login(request.get_full_path())
        return super(CreatorUpdate, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

**urls.py**

```
path('claim/<uuid:pk>', login_required(views.ClaimRedirectView.as_view()), name='claim')
path('creator/<slug:slug>/update/', views.CreatorUpdate.as_view(), name='creator-update')
```

**creator_form.html**

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}

{% block content %}

{% if messages %}
  {% for message in messages %}
  <p{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}><strong>{{ message }}</strong></p>
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}

<form action="" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_ul }}
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

When implementing the above `ClaimRedirectView` as suggested by @ I get to the form to fill in more information and see the correct url (having the next logic). But when filling in the form I do not get directed to the next part of the url. May this have something to do with the form (generic `UpdateView`) itself?

Comment: What you need to use is a RedirectView https://kite.com/python/docs/django.views.generic.base.RedirectView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting together parts of my original code and suggestions from @jackotonye I got it working with the following code:

**views.py**

```
from django.contrib import messages
from django.views.generic import RedirectView
class ClaimRedirectView(RedirectView):
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'street', 'street_number', 'zip_code', 'state_province', 'location', 'country']

    permanent = False

    def get_redirect_url(self, pk, *args, **kwargs):
        claimant = get_object_or_404(Creator, user=self.request.user)
        missing_fields = [fields.name for fields in claimant._meta.get_fields(include_hidden=False) if fields.name in self.REQUIRED_FIELDS and not getattr(claimant, fields.attname, None)]

        if not missing_fields:
            piece_instance = PieceInstance.objects.get(pk=pk)
            piece_instance.claimant = self.request.user
            piece_instance.date_claimed = datetime.date.today()
            piece_instance.status = 'c'
            piece_instance.save()
            return reverse('my-claimed')

        messages.info(self.request, 'Please fill in your complete address to proceed')
        next = self.request.get_full_path()

        path = reverse('creator-update', kwargs={'slug': claimant.slug})
        q = 'next=' + next

        return '%s?%s' % (path, q)

class CreatorUpdate(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Creator
    slug_field = 'slug'
    fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'street', 'street_number', 'zip_code', 'location', 'state_province', 'country']

    # these two methods only give access to the users own profile but not the others
    def user_passes_test(self, request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            self.object = self.get_object()
            return self.object.user == request.user
        return False

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.user_passes_test(request):
            return redirect_to_login(request.get_full_path())
        return super(CreatorUpdate, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_success_url(self):
        if 'next' in str(self.request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')):
            return self.request.GET.get('next', '/')
        return reverse_lazy('creator-detail', kwargs={'slug': self.object.slug})
```

**urls.py**

```
path('claim/<uuid:pk>', login_required(views.ClaimRedirectView.as_view()), name='claim')
path('creator/<slug:slug>/update/', views.CreatorUpdate.as_view(), name='creator-update')
```

The two crucial steps to success regarding the problem I had were to actually fill in and save the arguments in the `ClaimRedirectView` at `if not missing_fields:` and defining the `get_success_url` method in `CreatorUpdate`. The `get_success_url` manually checks if the string `next` is in the url and redirects accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Since the view redirects the request a better alternative will be to use a RedirectView and `next` isn't added to the url config hence the error.

It should be a querystring and the `CreatorUpdate.get_absolute_url` should be able to retrieve the param from the `GET` dict. i.e `request.GET.get('next')`

```
from django.http import QueryDict

class ClaimRedirectView(RedirectView):
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name', ...]

    permanent = False

    def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
        claimant = get_object_or_404(Creator, user=self.request.user)
        missing_fields = [
            f.name for fields in claimant._meta.get_fields(include_hidden=False)
            if f.name in REQUIRED_FIELDS and not getattr(claimant, f.attname, None)
        ]

        if not missing_fields:
            return reverse('my-claimed')

        messages.info(request, 'Please fill in your complete address to proceed')
        next = request.get_full_path()

        path = reverse('creator-update', kwargs={'slug': claimant.slug}))
        q = QueryDict('next=%s' % next)

        return '%s?%s' % (path, q.urlencode())
```

And the urls.py with a configuration the `<next:next>` isn't a kwarg i.e not a named group.

```
path('creator/<slug:slug>/update/', views.CreatorUpdate.as_view(), name='creator-update')
path('claim/<uuid:pk>', login_required(views.claim), name='claim')
```

To use the next as the redirect path on CreatorUpdate view.

```
class CreatorUpdate(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Creator
    slug_field = 'slug' # <-- This is already the default
    fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'street', 'street_number', 'zip_code', 'location', 'state_province', 'country']

    # This should be done using the `get_queryset`
    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super().get_queryset()
        # if request.user.is_authenticated: # Using the LoginRequiredMixin mixin users will already be authenticated.
        return qs.filter(user=self.request.user)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        next = self.request.GET.get('next')
        if next:
            return redirect(next)
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: this seems to almost get it. When I try to claim the piece without having provided all my address information it redirects me to the form to enter the information and the url points (with the next logic) to the correct next. However when clicking submit in the form I am not directed to the next part but the detail view of the user. May this have something to do with the form itself? I added some more information in the original question.

Comment: You'll need to update the CreatorUpdate view changing the `form_valid` to redirect using the next instead of the `.get_absolute_url`

Comment: I implemented these suggestions but seem not to get there. Also, it seems you are still using erroneous code, such as one of the urls (```views.claim```) and only ```request``` instead of ```self. request``` (which I edited in your answer). When implementing your suggestions, again I do see the correct part of the URL behind ```next``` but when filling in the form I am redirected to the form with the field I just filled in being empty. All seems fine, except for the actual redirect after successfully filling in the form.

Comment: The suggestions contains code that should be implemented alongside your implementation not supposed to be a verbatim implementation the urls are what you added above in the question no changes have been made only describing the expected implementation you should call save after saving the form and use the next path as the redirect url.

Answer (score 0):

Just like in the native `login_required`, you save the path to the `next` GET parameter:

```
def claim(request, pk):
    claimant = Creator.objects.get(user=request.user)
    if claimant.first_name != None and claimant.last_name != None and claimant.street != None and claimant.street_number != None and claimant.zip_code != None and claimant.location != None and claimant.state_province != None::
        (...)
    else:
        next = request.get_full_path()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('creator-update', kwargs={'slug': claimant.slug, 'next': next}))
```

and then in the `creator-update` view you check if there is next and redirect to that after a successful update. You might store the URL in a hidden input field.

I suggest checking the Django internals regarding this, specifically `django.contrib.auth.user_passes_test`, `django.contrib.auth.views.redirect_to_login` and `django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView`. It's no magic at all, everything there is very straightforward. For `LoginView` you should be familiar with class-based views.

Comment: when including the ```next``` parameter to be given to the URL I get a ```NoReverseMatch``` error since the URL redirecting to the update view only takes one argument. I added some more code in the original question. Since that way I don't even reach the creator-update view, do you see a way around this?